# Disable WordPress plugin for specific theme

Tags: wordpress

I have a regular theme and a mobile theme, and I would like to disable a plugin when using the mobile theme because it is causing problems (but I need to keep the plugin enabled for the regular theme). Is there any way to disable a specific plugin for a specific theme in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could use the is_phone call to remove an specific function in the plugin that is screwing things up.  Not sure on disabling a plugin entirely.

```
<?php if ( $is_iphone ) {
          remove_action( $tag, $function_to_remove, $priority, $accepted_args );
     } 
?>
```

More on removing funcions and filters [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)